# Windows Phone Display image

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

All My data photo is in server Example url: http://abcd.com/images/ and i have renamed all the photos file to my album id example 1.jpg,2.jpg
and i want to display those photos using albumid in grid view

```
class AlbumData
{
    public Int32 AlbumId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Language { get; set; }
    public String Actors { get; set; }
    public String Director { get; set; }
    public String MusicDirector { get; set; }
    public String Year { get; set; }
}

private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://albums.abcd.com/v1/Albums/English/1"));//--getting data using xml 

    }
    void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");

        }


        XElement XmlTweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        listBox1.ItemsSource = from tweet in XmlTweet.Descendants("Album")
                               select new AlbumData()
                               {
                                  Name = tweet.Element("Name").Value,
                                  //--how to display image---//
                               };
    }
```

Please help me with example

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="15" Width="120" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="8" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" />-->
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding MusicDirector}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="8" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"  />-->
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"/>-->
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you please write functional code and xaml and specify your problem?

Comment: i have updated the functional code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ElementName of your images is *ImageUri*, you must change your ItemsSource to:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = 
    from tweet in XmlTweet.Descendants("Album")
    select new AlbumData()
    {
        Name = tweet.Element("Name").Value,
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tweet.Element("ImageUri"), UriKind.Relative));
    };
```

AlbumData needs to be extended by

```
public BitmapImage ImageSource { get; set; }
```

Comment: Actual Xml Data where Im getting just consist of AlbumId,Name,Actor,Director,MusicDirectoryear wat ur saying is to create  new Uri("http://abcd.com/images/1.jpg"));                   ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tweet.Element("ImageUri"), UriKind.Relative)); but i have multiple images to load

Comment: Do they belong to the Album? If the XML does not contain the Image, how do you know, what image you must load?